# How to reproduce conda environments that has packages installed with conda and pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I have a conda environment that has some packages installed with `conda install` and some packages installed with `pip install`. I need to recreate that environment with all same versions of packages installed with both `conda install` and `pip install`. How can I do it?

Comment: `conda env export` will capture both Conda and Pip-installed packages.